# How to restrict Multiple wildcard search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, frontend

I have an object called "param" which will be passed as a parameter in an API call

```
param = { "prodNbr":["ABC1%", "DEF1%], "skuNbr":["MNO1%","KLM2%"], "prodCd":[]}
```

I need to validate certain conditions

1. How can I restrict multiple % (wild card search) in this object (User can search with only one `%`. If multiple `%` is used, it should throw error)
2. Minimum three character should be required if searching with % (wildcard search) and `%` should be after 3 or more character (eg: `ABC%` or `ABC1%`)  Please help

Answer (score 0):

1) An easy way is checking if the index of first apparition is different from last one : `str.indexOf("%") != str.lastIndexOf("%");`

2) Just check that first apparition is at index 3 or gretear

So :

```
if (str.includes("%")) {
    if (str.indexOf("%") != str.lastIndexOf("%") || str.indexOf("%") < 3) {
        alert("error");
    } else {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juvian for your quick reply. Thanks a lot

Comment: Lets say I converted the values of object param into an Array
[ "ABC1%,DEF1%, MNO1%,KLM2%" ]
How can I check % is not occurring more than once (Means, if one element contains %, no other element in that Array should contain %. In this scenario 4 elements are having %, which should throw error)

Comment: @Bijil Well depends, can a single element have more than 1 % ? If not, you can just check if the stringified version has % with str = array.join(',')

Comment: I have done the same thing. Converted this into an array and checked whether % is occurring more than once and also if  one % is present, it's index should be greater than 2.